# Repeat python command until x time has passed

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, python

I have the following problem, my python script due to some (known) reason crashes in the early running stages 99 out of 100 times. But as that program is not written by me I am not sure how to fix it. So I thought maybe I could just repeatedly restart the script until it finishes successfully.

Is there a way to do this? I've seen multiple ways to automatically restart a program every x seconds, but I want to only restart the program when it didn't run longer than x minutes. So if it runs for more than x mins, don't restart it if it terminates (as it will finish successfully), but if it crashes within x min restart it (as it didn't run successfully).

Is this possible?

For me, x would be ~30 min as the algorithm can run for some time until it crashes and if it runs successfully it will take more than 2 h to run.

Comment: "_as that program is not written by me I am not sure how to fix it_" - can you ask the author?

Comment: Would it help to solve the problem differently? Can the program notify that it is done, like create an empty file? And then restart if the file does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I thought maybe I could just repeatedly restart the script until it finishes successfully.

This is easy. The following would repeat your command once/second until it is successful:

```
until python myscript.py; do
  sleep 1
done
```

> I've seen multiple ways to automatically restart a program every x seconds, but I want to only restart the program, when it didn't run longer than x minutes.

A little bit trickier, but you could use the `timeout` command (part of `coreutils`, so you should have it) to wrap the previous script. The following would retry your script every second for a maximum of five minutes:

```
timeout 5m sh -c 'until python myscript.py; do sleep 1; done'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this kind of works, but it quits my program after 5 min too. The program itself will run at least 2-3 hours though, so that's not an option.

Comment: I believe this exactly answers the question you have posed regarding limiting the maximum runtime of a retry operation. If it doesn't meet your needs it would help if you could update your question to show your additional requirements.